# How to update the GUI in Thread when use the Tkinter Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am developing a program to check website keywords using a URL list, and for ease of use, I have chosen to implement a GUI with Tkinter. However, I am facing difficulty in updating the treeview when dealing with data using multiple threads. Although I have used queues to update the GUI on the main thread, my program still becomes unresponsive at times.

The program is split into two files: logic.py and ui.py.

could i get some advice?

logic.py code:

```
import configparser
import csv
import requests
from retrying import retry
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import re
import json

class Logic:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    # Read configuration file information
    def read_config(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(r'config.ini', encoding='utf-8')
        # Get the value of the 'CSV_FILE_PATH' key under the 'DEFAULT' section
        csv_file_path = config['DEFAULT']['CSV_FILE_PATH']
        # Get the value of the 'KEYWORD' key under the 'DEFAULT' section and split it into a list of keywords
        keywords = [keyword.lower() for keyword in config['DEFAULT']['KEYWORD'].split(',')]
        #print(keywords)
        return csv_file_path, keywords

    # Read URL information from csv file
    def read_csv(self, csv_file_path):
        urls = []
        with open(csv_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                urls.append(row['url'])
        return urls

    # Access URL to get source code and other information
    @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3, wait_fixed=1000)
    def get_url_response(self, url):
        Proxies={
            'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:10809',
            'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:10809'  # https -> http
        }
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, proxies=Proxies)
        #response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, proxies=Proxies, verify=False)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise requests.exceptions.RequestException('HTTP status code error')
        return response

    # Check if keywords exist regardless of case
    def check_keyword(self, source_code, keywords):
        # Convert keywords in the keyword list to regular expression patterns
        patterns = [re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(keyword), re.IGNORECASE) for keyword in keywords]

        # Check if each keyword exists in the source code
        matches = [pattern.search(source_code) for pattern in patterns]

        # Build a JSON dictionary that contains all keywords and their existence status
        result_dict = {}
        for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
            if matches[i]:
                result_dict[keyword] = True
            else:
                result_dict[keyword] = False

        # Print the JSON dictionary
        #print(json.dumps(result_dict, indent=4))

        return result_dict

    # Write the result dictionary to the CSV file
    def write_csv_row(self, url, result_dict, error=None):
        with open('result.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['url'] + list(result_dict.keys()) + ['error']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            # If the CSV file does not exist, write the header
            if csvfile.tell() == 0:
                writer.writeheader()

            # Determine whether to write "Exists" or "Not Exists" based on the value of the result dictionary
            row_data = {'url': url}
            for key, value in result_dict.items():
                if value:
                    row_data[key] = 'Exists'
                else:
                    row_data[key] = 'Not Exists'
            
            # Write error message if there is one
            if error:
                row_data['error'] = error
            else:
                row_data['error'] = ''
            # Write data to CSV file
            writer.writerow(row_data)
            # Add data to the queue
            self.app.msg_queue.put(row_data)


    # Process a single URL
    def process_url(self, urls, url, keywords):
        total_count = len(urls)
        try:
            # Access URL to get source code
            response = self.get_url_response(url)
            source_code = response.text.lower()

            # Check if keywords exist and return result dictionary
            result_dict = self.check_keyword(source_code, keywords)

            # Write the result dictionary to the CSV file
            self.write_csv_row(url, result_dict)
            total_count = len(urls)
            #print('URL: {} processed'.format(url))
        
        except Exception as e:
            #print('URL: {} processing failed with error: {}'.format(url, str(e)))
            self.write_csv_row(url, {}, error=str(e))

    # Process all URLs
    def process_all_urls(self, urls, keywords):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            for url in urls:
                executor.submit(self.process_url, urls, url, keywords)

    def start_check(self, csv_file_path, keywords):
    
        # Read URL information from CSV file
        urls = self.read_csv(csv_file_path)

        # Process all URLs
        self.process_all_urls(urls, keywords)
```

ui.py code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog, simpledialog, messagebox
from logic import Logic
import threading
import queue as Queue


class App:
    msg_queue = None # Create a queue
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("URL Checker")
        
        self.msg_queue = Queue.Queue() # Create a queue
        self.initGUI(master)

        # Create a button for selecting CSV files
        self.choose_file_button = tk.Button(master, text="Select CSV File", command=self.choose_file)
        self.choose_file_button.pack()

        # Create a label for displaying the current keyword and a button for modifying the keyword
        self.keyword_label = tk.Label(master, text="Current Keyword:")
        self.keyword_label.pack()
        self.change_keyword_button = tk.Button(master, text="Modify Keyword", command=self.change_keyword)
        self.change_keyword_button.pack()

        # Create a listbox for displaying the checking results
        self.result_treeview = ttk.Treeview(master)
        self.result_treeview.pack()

        # Create a button for starting the checking process
        self.start_button = tk.Button(master, text="Start Checking", command=self.start_checking)
        self.start_button.pack()
        
        # Initialize variables
        self.csv_file_path = None
        self.keywords = []
        self.urls = []
        self.results = []
        self.checking_thread = None
        self.is_paused = False
    
    # Update the header of the result treeview
    def update_result_treeview_header(self):
        self.result_treeview['columns'] = ["URL"] + self.keywords
        self.result_treeview.heading("#0", text="No.")
        self.result_treeview.column("#0", width=50)
        self.result_treeview.heading("URL", text="URL")
        for keyword in self.keywords:
            self.result_treeview.heading(keyword, text=keyword)

    def choose_file(self):
        # Pop up a file selection dialog to choose CSV files
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
        if file_path:
            self.csv_file_path = file_path
            print(self.csv_file_path)
            logic = Logic(self)
            self.urls = logic.read_csv(self.csv_file_path)

    def change_keyword(self):
        # Pop up a dialog to modify the keyword
        new_keywords = simpledialog.askstring("Modify Keyword", "Please enter new keywords, separated by commas:", parent=self.master)
        if new_keywords:
            self.keywords = [keyword.strip().lower() for keyword in new_keywords.split(',')]
            #self.keywords.append("erro")
            self.keyword_label.config(text=f"Current Keyword: {', '.join(self.keywords)}")
            self.update_result_treeview_header()
            #print(self.keywords)

    # Retrieve and process messages from the queue            
    def handee(self,root):
        # Retrieve the contents of the queue and assign them to label controls
        mpica=self.msg_queue.empty()# Check if the queue is empty
        if(mpica==False):
            data=self.msg_queue.get()
            values = list(data.values())
            output_string = ' '.join(str(value) for value in values)
            self.result_treeview.insert('', 'end', value = output_string)       
        root.after(200, self.handee,root)# Recursively call to implement loop. In TKinter UI thread, traditional while loops cannot be used and can only be implemented recursively using this built-in function.
    
    # Refresh the processing queue
    def initGUI(self, root):
        root.after(100, self.handee,root)
    
    # Start checking (start button function)    
    def start_checking(self):
        if not self.csv_file_path:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a CSV file first.")
            return

        if not self.keywords:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please set the keyword first.")
            return

        if not self.urls:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "There are no URLs in the CSV file.")
            return

        # Clear the result listbox
        #self.result_treeview.delete(0, tk.END)
        
        # Call logic to start checking
        logic = Logic(self)
        logic.start_check(self.csv_file_path, self.keywords)


def main():
    try:
        # Initialize the Tkinter GUI
        root = tk.Tk()
        app = App(master=root)
        
        root.mainloop()
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: btw, calls to `after()`, like: `root.after(200, self.handee,root)` are technically not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

`queue.get()` is blocking - you can use `queue.get_nowait()` to perform a non-blocking get, but bear in mind that this will raise `queue.Empty` if there's nothing in the queue. The easiest fix for that is to wrap the `get_nowait` in a `try:except` block and `pass` on `queue.Empty`. Once you've made this change, you can also ditch the check for `self.msg_queue.empty()` since it's handled by the `try:except` block!

Also, as an aside, capitalized names like `Queue` are typically reserved for classes in Python, so you should probably just `import queue` instead of `import queue as Queue` to avoid confusion!

```
def handee(self,root):
    # Retrieve the contents of the queue and assign them to label controls
    try:
        data = self.msg_queue.get_nowait()  # perform non-blocking get
    except queue.Empty:
        pass  # nothing in the queue, nothing to do
    else:
        values = list(data.values())
        output_string = ' '.join(str(value) for value in values)
        self.result_treeview.insert('', 'end', value = output_string)
    root.after(200, self.handee,root) # Recursively call to implement loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer and great advice, Your code worked, and more better than mine. but the problem still being there:
when I click the start-checking button, the GUI will be nonresponse for a while and can't move the window, After a while(the program is finished) the window can be moved and start updating
I'm a freshman in Python and programming, and can't find out the reason